# When registering an HttpModule for Sharepoint, where should the assembly reside?

Tags: asp.net

Meaning where in the path of the Sharepoint web site/app should the assembly reside? My module is currently not being loaded. Does it have to be in the GAC?

Answer (score 1):

It does need to be in the GAC in any servers that could possibly run your module (if it's pertaining to a web page, that means all web front ends). You can have SharePoint 2010 automatically deploy solution files to your farm, a process that includes automatically deploying .dll's to the GAC.

```
$solution = Add-SPSolution c:/pathname/solution.wsp
Install-SPSolution $solution -gacdeployment
```